# Can someone explain how the Quaternion works for MoveBaseActions?

Tags: ros, move-base-msgs, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really want to be able to send  a goal to move base that is it's current position, but a different orientation/ rotation. I know I can send a twist command to rotate the robot, but I was wondering how someone would do it via MoveBase?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40332/can-someone-explain-how-the-quaternion-works-for-movebaseactions?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9981/what-are-quaternions-and-how-can-i-use-them/) to understand quaternions.

To rotate the robot, you can, for instance, send a PoseStamped with frame id `base_link` and the relative orientation of your goal relative to your robot to move_base.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are sure of the quaternion values. You can simply publish using geometry_msgs/PoseStamped. Sample:

```
    publisher = nh.advertise<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionGoal>("move_base/goal", 5);
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped GoalPose;
    move_base_msgs::MoveBaseActionGoal Goal_Pose;
        
    GoalPose.pose.position.x = <current pose x>;
    GoalPose.pose.position.y = <current pose y>;
    GoalPose.pose.position.z = <current pose z>;

    GoalPose.pose.orientation.x = <desired orientation x>;
    GoalPose.pose.orientation.y = <desired orientation y>;
    GoalPose.pose.orientation.z = <desired orientation z>;
    GoalPose.pose.orientation.w = <desired orientation w>;
        
    Goal_Pose.header.seq = GoalPose.header.seq = 1;
    GoalPose.header.stamp = 1;
    Goal_Pose.header.frame_id = GoalPose.header.frame_id = "/map";

    Goal_Pose.goal.target_pose = GoalPose;
    publisher.publish(Goal_Pose);
```

I used the above on a TurtleBot and it worked perfectly!

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-01**:
This will send the robot to a different location in map unless the correct x and y values for position are used. It is much easier to set the frame_id to base_link and the position to 0. Why are you setting the stamp to 1? This should not work. Set the time to ros::Time::now() or 0.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For robots moving in 2D space, I usually use

```
GoalPose.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(<desired direction>);
```

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2